# How to get value in textbox and display value into modal bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

This is the php code: retrieve name from database and tape the contact number. click the button how much have to top up and display how much, name and contact number into the modal and click yes.

```
        <button type="submit"  data-target="#topup10" class="btn  btn-default"    data-toggle="modal" >TOPUP <br> RM 10.60</button> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">TOPUP <br> RM 31.80</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">TOPUP <br> RM 53.00</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">TOPUP <br> RM 106.00</button>
        </div>
        <form name="getdata" method="post" action="">
            <div>

                <h5>TAG THIS SALE ORDER TO THE FOLLOWING CUSTOMER</h5>
                <div class="col-xs-3">

                    <!-- display for customer name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Contact Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['cust_name'])) {echo $_POST['cust_name'];}?>">                     
                    </div>


                    <!-- display for contact number -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="no">Contact Number</label>
                        <!--<input class="form-control" id="no" type="text" value="<?php /*if (isset($_POST['cust_hp_contact1'])) {echo $_POST['cust_hp_contact1'];}*/?>">-->
                        <input class="form-control" id="no" name="no" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <p></p>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                </div>

                <!-- display RM10 -->
                <div id="topup10" class="modal fade">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">

                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title"><img src="img/imgtopup/btncelcom.jpg"  class="img-rounded" width=70" height="60">Maxis RM10.00</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">

                                        Are you sure?<br>
                                        Name: <?php if (isset($_POST['cust_name'])) {echo $_POST['cust_name'];}?> <br>
                                        Contact Number: <?php
                                                                       $test = $_POST['no'];
                                                                       echo $test;
                                                        ?>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <a href="#topup10" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Yes</button>
                            </div>
```

1. How I can get value form contact number textbox pass value and display in modal bootstrap?
2. I try to modified many isset there also cannot display the result. Thanks

Comment: some buttons outside form tags.

Comment: yup, if I put the 4 button inside form the modal not working.

Comment: and not name attribute element for `cust_name`

Comment: cust_name is retrieve data from database, that one is okay. i want to tape contact number only

Comment: error: `Notice: Undefined index: no in C:\xampp\htdocs\fimosproject\topupcelcom.php on line 85`

Comment: which means I dont understand. can u guide me? Thanks

Comment: here you go to pass value from input to modal http://jsfiddle.net/9pkbnanz/5/

Answer (score 2):

Assuming following is the form (no idea why you need the form here)

```
<form name="getdata" method="post" action="">
<h5>TAG THIS SALE ORDER TO THE FOLLOWING CUSTOMER</h5>
<div class="col-xs-3">
<!-- display for customer name -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Contact Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="name" type="text" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['cust_name'])) {echo $_POST['cust_name'];}?>">                     
    </div>
    <!-- display for contact number -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="no">Contact Number</label>
        <!--<input class="form-control" id="no" type="text" value="<?php /*if (isset($_POST['cust_hp_contact1'])) {echo $_POST['cust_hp_contact1'];}*/?>">-->
        <input class="form-control" id="no" name="no" type="text">
    </div>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Following are TOP-UP buttons

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">TOPUP <br> RM 31.80</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">TOPUP <br> RM 53.00</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">TOPUP <br> RM 106.00</button>
```

add values (prices) as data attribute e.g `data-price` in buttons, also these buttons will also handle the modal call too so change them as following

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-target="#topup"  data-toggle="modal" data-price="31.80">TOPUP <br> RM 31.80</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-target="#topup"  data-toggle="modal" data-price="353.00">TOPUP <br> RM 53.00</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-target="#topup"  data-toggle="modal" data-price="106.00">TOPUP <br> RM 106.00</button>
```

And Now Modal HTML (You don't need multiple modals, one modal can do the job)

```
<div id="topup" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"><img src="img/imgtopup/btncelcom.jpg"  class="img-rounded" width="70" height="60">Maxis RM10.00</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            Are you sure?<br>
            <label>TopUP: <span id="TopUP"></span></label>
            <label>Name:  <span id="Name"></span></label>
            <label>Contact Number:  <span id="Contact"></span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#topup" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Yes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now to pass values from `form inputs` to modal, can be done with [modal event listeners](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events).

```
$('#topup').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    //
});
```

create variables to get input values and declare them in `modal event listeners` along with fetch the price from `data-price` attribute by `e.relatedTarget`

```
$('#topup').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var price = $(e.relatedTarget).data('price');
    var contact = $('#name').val();
    var number = $('#no').val();
});
```

Now you have `price`, `contact` and `number` variables ready, now pass them to modal, i added following HTML code in modal to show the variable values

```
<label>TopUP: <span id="TopUP"></span></label>
<label>Name:  <span id="Name"></span></label>
<label>Contact Number:  <span id="Contact"></span></label>
```

so final Script will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#topup').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var price = $(e.relatedTarget).data('price');
        var contact = $('#name').val();
        var number = $('#no').val();
        //Pass Values
        $('#TopUP').html(price);
        $('#Name').html(contact);
        $('#Contact').html(number);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pkbnanz/7/)

Comment: Thanks I get your means. If I want to retrieve name from database also can right?

Comment: how I can apply into my form? after clicked button topup didnt display result what I key in display in modal. @Shehary