# Bootstrap 4 Model Pass Value

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I can't work out how to submit data to a modal - for example:

```
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var userID = $(this).data('userId');
    $('#passUser').trigger('focus')
})
```

The example is taken directly from the bootstrap documentation, with the exception of passing data and the form.

```
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" id="passUser" data-userId="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)">
            Launch demo modal
     </button>
```

The button has the correct ID value, but I dont know how to pass that, or even just some text to the modal.

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Show Value userID!
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33353396/10972795

Not sure why the above wasn't working